# Passing multiple values with GetElementById (& Split after certain a character)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, split, webforms, getelementbyid

I have little to no experience of JavaScript but I do know that the getElementID only carries one value so how can I have 2 values passed? 
Can I use it twice like I have down below or would I be better to use another GetElementBy/GetElementsBy method to do it?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
           hash();
            function hash() {
                var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++) {
                    var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
                    document.getElementById("<%=start.ClientID%>").value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
                    document.getElementById("<%=end.ClientID%>").value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);;
                }
                
            }
        });
 </script>
```

**EDIT**
So I've decided to use the loop twice and its working but the values I'm passing contain text I need removed. Is there a way in which I can cut off the split after a certain character? Here is my new code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
             hash();
            function hash() {
                var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('#');
                for (var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++) {
                    var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
                    document.getElementById("<%=start.ClientID%>").value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
                }
                var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < hashParams.length; i++) {
                    var p = hashParams[i].split('=');
                    document.getElementById("<%=end.ClientID%>").value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);;
                }
                
            }
        });
 </script>
```

And here is the text that appears in the search bar when forwarded from the previous page. 
localhost:56363/Bookings.aspx#start=27/02/2018 12:30&end=27/02/2018 17:30

The start and end input boxes fill with the values but the start input box (27/02/2018 12:30&end) has characters I want cut off (&end). 
Is there a way to stop a split after a certain character?

Comment: getElementById will need to be called each time you want to get an element from the DOM by Id. There may be more efficient ways of calling multiple elements from the DOM than by Id. For example, you could getElementsByName if you need to loop through a group of elements with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

Using it twice as you have is perfectly acceptable. And, if they are separate things, then it makes sense.

While you could also use `getElementsByTagName()`, `getElementsByName()` or `getElementsByClassName()`, usually using `document.querySelectorAll()` is the more modern choice.

If they have something in common with them (like say a class), you could use it like this:

```
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.classToGet');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodeList, element => element.value = decodeURIComponent(p[1]));
```

`document.querySelectorAll()` (as well as the `getElementsBy` functions) return a `NodeList`, which is kind of like an `Array`, but doesn't have an Array's functions, so you need to `Array.prototype.forEach.call()` to loop over them.

`document.querySelectorAll()` accepts a string like you would give to CSS, and the NodeList has all elements that match that.

And FYI, there is an equivalent `document.querySelector()` which gets a single element, so you could use it for IDs:

```
document.querySelector("#<%=start.ClientID%>")
```

Note the `#` like you would have for CSS at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

ID is a unique identifier, unlike class, so there should be only one of it with the same name in your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

getElementById is intended to find the one element in the DOM with the specified ID.

If you need to get multiple elements, then yes make multiple calls to getElementById.

See here for the documentation on the getElementById method showing that it only accepts a single ID parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById